# Can I manually override inherited methods?

Tags: java, generics, signature, overwrite

That's a very imperfect title...

```
public class A extends AbstractList
{
   public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<E> what){}
}
```

but Eclipse gives me the compile error

```
Name clash: The method addAll(int, Collection<E>) of type DynamicArray<E> has the same
erasure as addAll(int, Collection<? extends E>) of type AbstractList<E> but does not 
override it
```

I understand what the problem with the erasure is, but I don't understand why `addAll(int, Collection<E>)` doesn't override the inherited method it's having conflicts with (If both were defined in the same class I could see it, but the problem is: "When a method has the same erasure as an inherited method, we override the inherited method. But this one has the same erasure, so it won't work").

Is there any way to force the compiler to overwrite `AbstractList.addAll(int, Collection<? extends E>)` with `DynamicList.addAll(int, Collection<E>)`?

Comment: Close as I can understand it (the rules for this are pretty arcane), the complaint is that your function definition effectively blocks access to the original function, but it will not accept (compile without type conflict) all legal calls to the original.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the exact same signature as the method to be overridden:

```
 public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E> what)
```

> Is there any way to force the compiler to overwrite `AbstractList.addAll(int, Collection<? extends E>)` with `DynamicList.addAll(int, Collection<E>)`?

If you are thinking of overloading: No. The two methods could not be distinguished because of erasure. So there can be only one.

If you are thinking of overriding: Well, if you specify a different signature, that would not be overriding, would it? You could not narrow Collection to ArrayList in the signature, either, right?

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, the original `addAll(int, Collection<? extends E>)` states that the second parm can be any collection of items that may extend E, while your version `addAll(int, Collection<E>)` requires that the items be E exactly, and they cannot extend E.